# Open URL's in MS Edge and reuse the same tab

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium, microsoft-edge-extension, microsoft-edge-chromium

Today we have an application that has a button which opens IE11 with a tab with customer id as argument.
For each button click it reuse the existing IE11 tab.

We need to have the same behavior with MS Edge but I have not found any way to do this.
Thinking of passing some argument to edge with "tab-id" e.g.

`start msedge --tab-id=myapp https://www.example.com/app?customer_id=123`

I am out of ideas :( and would appreciate some input

Is there any way to do this with MS Edge?

- MS Edge arguments?
- Extensions?
- JavaScript?
- ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up with separate Edge profile and installed xTab extension with 1 tab limit and starting Edge with
`start msedge --profile-directory="profile-name" https://example.com/app?customer_id=123`

Answer (score 0):

If your application is running in Edge, then you can implement your requirement with simple JavaScript code, just use the `window.open()` function.

You just need to specify the same `strWindowName` of its parameters to achieve your desired result.

```
window.open('https://www.example.com/app?customer_id=123','my-app')
window.open('https://www.example.com/app?customer_id=456','my-app')
```